Why does Livewire not recognize my input name?
I use Livewire 3, I don't know why when I try to send my input, it shows an error in the console:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name')
Example of my input
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
   <label for="inputName4">Name</label>
   <input wire:model.lazy="user.name" type="text" class="@error('user.name') is-invalid @enderror form-control" id="inputName4">
   @error('user.name')
      <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
   @enderror
</div>

This is the backend side
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Auth;

use App\Models\User;
use Livewire\Component;

class Register extends Component
{
    public User $user;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->user = new User();
    }
    protected $rules = [
        'user.name' => 'required|min:4',
        'user.email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'user.password' => 'required|min:8',
    ];

    public function register()
    {
        $this->validate();

        dd($this->user);
    }
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.auth.register');
    }
}

But it does not recognize the validation of inputs

do you have the  tag?
